# perl iterate through directories

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get the name of all directories in the specified path

I tried the following but that gives me every level down not just at the path i specified

```
find(\&dir_names, "C:\\mydata\\");
sub dir_names {
    print "$File::Find::dir\n" if(-f $File::Find::dir,'/');
}
```

Comment: "every level down" does sound like what you are asking for in the title: "iterate through directories".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
my @dirs = grep { -d } glob 'C:\mydata\*';
```

Comment: thanks a lot FMc, worked like a charm! can u please explain what -d does, I know grep and global but not able to figure out what { -d } does. Thanks

Comment: @ParikshitTiwari It filters the result of the glob down to just directories. It's one of many file-test operators: see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html.

Answer (score 8):

Use `opendir` instead

```
opendir DIR, $dirname or die "Couldn't open dir '$dirname': $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR); 
closedir DIR; 
#next processing...
```

**EDIT:**

> "This will give all the files, not just the directories. You'd still have to grep."

Yes, and in that case you can just use file test operator to see whether it's a directory or not.

In Windows:

```
$dirname="C:\\";
opendir(DIR, $dirname);
@files = readdir(DIR);
closedir DIR;
foreach $key (@files)
 {
  if(-d "$dirname\\$key")
   {
     print "$key\n";
   }
 }
```

Comment: This will give all the files, not just the directories. You'd still have to grep.

Comment: You will probably want to skip the directories with only dots in them too in your foreach loop `next if $key eq "." || $key eq "..";`

Answer (score 1):

See chapter 2 *Filesystems* from [Automating System Administration with Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006396/). That provides us with this:

```
sub ScanDirectory{
    my ($workdir) = shift;
    chdir($workdir) or die "Unable to enter dir $workdir:$!\n";
    opendir(DIR, ".") or die "Unable to open $workdir:$!\n";
    my @names = readdir(DIR) or die "Unable to read $workdir:$!\n";
    closedir(DIR);

    foreach my $name (@names){
        next if ($name eq "."); 
        next if ($name eq "..");

        if (-d $name){                  # is this a directory?
            #Whatever you want to do goes here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is wrong you need this for it to work correctly if (-d "$workdir\\$name")

Answer (score 0):

`glob` or `readdir` would probably be my choice too. Another way to do it is to use the windows `dir` command to do the job:

```
my @dirs = qx(dir /AD /B);
chomp @dirs;
```