# Perl: Splitting a variable containing a path to directory

Tags: regex, perl, path, split

So I'm having a problem trying to split a variable that has the complete path to a directory. I want to fetch the files under 'logs' directory of this path:
'/nfs/fm/disks/fm_mydiskhere_00000/users/me/repotest/myrepo/tools/toolsdir/logs/*';

and in my Perl script, I have a variable that contains this path: '$log_file'. When I print '$log_file', it contains the entire path; I want to go to the last directory 'logs' and fetch the files under it. By the way, this complete path is in a separate configuration file that is being read by my Perl script this way:

```
sub read_file {
my ($log_file) = shift(@_);

info ("Using file : $log_file");
my $fh = new FileHandle ("$log_file");
printError ("Could not open this file : '$log_file' - $!") unless defined $fh;

my $contents;
{
    local $/ = undef;
    $contents = <$fh>;
}
$fh->close();
eval $contents;
if ($@) {
    chomp $@;
    my $msg = "BAD (perl) syntax in file:\n\n$@\n";
    if ( $msg =~ /requires explicit package name/ ) {
        $msg .= "\n  -> A 'requires explicit package name' message means".
            " a NON-VALID variable name was found\n";
    }
    die "Error: $msg\n\n";
}
return 1;
```

}

And I'm using variable $log_file in another subroutine this way:

```
my $fh = read_file ($log_file);
if ($log_file eq "abc.txt"){
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
#do something
}
}
```

Can anybody help me here, please? Am I missing something or using $log_file in the wrong way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing that `FileHandle` isn't able to accept wildcards. This makes sense because a File Handle is a handle to a single file. Try assigning a path to a single file into `$log_file` and see if that alleviates your problems.

Comment: I get your point..but under the directory '/logs', there are several files and I perform different operation on each file depending on its name. $log_file is reading the whole path ('/nfs/fm/disks/fm_mydiskhere_00000/users/me/repotest/myrepo/tools/toolsdir/logs/*';) , I'm not sure how to get it to read files from the last '/logs' directory.

Comment: How about using [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) to first iterate over each filename, then putting all your logic within that loop? Here's another stack overflow question/answer that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442889/perl-iterate-through-directories/6443023#6443023

Comment: Sure..Will try this and leave a comment as to what I see in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
my @files = glob($log_file);
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@files);
```

Comment: Tried to include the above snippet in my 'read_file' subroutine.This is what I get: $VAR1 = [
          '/nfs/fm/disks/fm_infrach_00022/users/npothuku/repotest/ip-psf2/tools/dynamo/logs/'
        ];

Comment: Just try what I suggested - you don't need to split `$log_file` up at all.  The `glob` handles all that for you, and will list all the files under the location pointed to by `$log_file` i.e. `my @files = glob('/nfs/fm/disks/fm_mydiskhere_00000/users/me/repotest/myrepo/tools/toolsdir/logs/*');` should give you the list of files you need.

Comment: The glob will return you the full filename, so rather than using `$log_file eq "abc.txt"` you can use `$log_file =~ /\/abc.txt$/` or use `File::Basename` to extract the filename without the path.

Comment: Since $log_file is fetching the path from a configuration file, I cannot hard code the path in my script. So I do this:  <code> my $log_file = $RC{path_from_config_file}; my @files = glob($log_file);
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@files); </code>

Comment: The `glob()` call needs a wildcard on the end to do what you want - does it have that in the config file?  If not, you'll need to do `glob("$log_file/*");`.

Comment: oh wait..It is listing all the files under '/logs' directory as expected. Now you suggest I use a pattern match instead of '$log_file eq "abc.txt"' to fetch the files I need? The array now looks like: $VAR1 = [ '/nfs/fm/disks/fm_mydiskhere_00000/users/me/repotest/myrepo/tools/toolsdir/‌​logs/abc.txt , ...(all files listed)]

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the files - if you want to open them, just use the full filename. If you want an `if` statement on the filename, then either match the full filename, or see my earlier comment.

Comment: [ '/nfs/fm/disks/fm_infrach_00022/users/npothuku/repotest/ip-psf2/tools/dynamo/logs/soctbCollage.dnv.log',
          '/nfs/fm/disks/fm_infrach_00022/users/npothuku/repotest/ip-psf2/tools/dynamo/logs/xregress_transcript_csme.log'] This is what I get as the elements of the '@files' array. If i want this one: 'xregress_transcript_csme.log' how would i get this name from the last element of the array?

Comment: As per my earlier comment, have a look at `basename()` in the [File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename) module.

Comment: Cool. Your suggestion on the earlier comment worked! I used basename for the @files array and now I have the file names fetched as required.